# How to add a Rating inside a TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, rating

In my Java Desktop Application I have a TableView in which I want to have a column with Rating stars from org.controlsfx.control.Rating.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Disciplina> tableFilter;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Disciplina, Rating> ratingColumn;
@FXML
private ObservableList<Disciplina> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I found something with .setCellValueFactory(new CallBack()) but I didn't understood how it works.
So how can I add those rating stars inside my table view?

Comment: Try looking at [this tutorial](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/03/javafx-embed-button-in-tableview.html). They use Button there, but it should be pretty similar.

Comment: This question is too broad for this forum: you need to try something and post a specific question if you can't get it to work. Note though that your table column type is wrong (assuming you  are referring to the ControlsFX `Rating` control here): `Rating` is a control; the type in the column should be the type of data displayed. `Rating` displays the value stored in a `DoubleProperty`, so you should have `private TableColumn<Disciplina, Number> ratingColumn` and use the cell factory to display a `Rating`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `cellValueFactory`, use the `cellFactory` to create the visual representation of the content in the column.

```
TableView<RatingItem> tableView = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new RatingItem(0),
        new RatingItem(2),
        new RatingItem(1),
        new RatingItem(4),
        new RatingItem(5)
));
tableView.setEditable(true);
TableColumn<RatingItem, Number> ratingColumn = new TableColumn<>("rating");
tableView.getColumns().add(ratingColumn);

// cellValueFactory gets value from item
ratingColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().ratingProperty());

// cellFactory creates UI representation
ratingColumn.setCellFactory(table -> new TableCell<RatingItem, Number>() {

    private final Rating rating;

    private final ChangeListener<Number> ratingChangeListener;

    {
        rating = new Rating(5);

        // listener for changes in rating
        ratingChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            TableColumn<?, Number> column = getTableColumn();

            // get the property used for this column (has to be WritableDoubleProperty)
            WritableDoubleValue value = (WritableDoubleValue) column.getCellValueFactory().call(new TableColumn.CellDataFeatures(getTableView(), column, getTableRow().getItem()));

            value.set(newValue.doubleValue());
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        rating.ratingProperty().removeListener(ratingChangeListener);

        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            rating.setRating(item.doubleValue());

            // only listen to changes done later through user interaction
            rating.ratingProperty().addListener(ratingChangeListener);
            setGraphic(rating);
        }
    }

});
```

```
public class RatingItem {

    private final DoubleProperty rating;

    public RatingItem(int rating) {
        this.rating = new SimpleDoubleProperty(rating);
    }

    public final double getRating() {
        return this.rating.get();
    }

    public final void setRating(double value) {
        this.rating.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty ratingProperty() {
        return this.rating;
    }

}
```